# How do I add cors header in a soap service in spring?

Tags: reactjs, spring, soap

I followed the "producing a soap service using spring" tutorial from the official [spring website](https://spring.io/guides/gs/producing-web-service/)

I tried making requests with postman and all has been working fine. I now want to be able to make requests from a website(a react frontend). I tried searching online but none of the methods worked. It always gives my a `No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin` error.

Other method which I could think of is to create a middle layer(express server) which then directs the frontend requests to the soap endpoint. But is this my only choice? Do
websites always implement communicating with soap services with a middle layer?

Comment: It’s complaining because the origin of the webpage differs from the origin of the soap endpoint, which you are calling from js. Very unusual scenario! You will have to get the site serving soap to permit your site’s cross-origin calls -https://spring.io/guides/gs/rest-service-cors/ Or, as you suggest, wrap the soap server in your fe server, so they appear to have the same origin. Or serve the react fe as a spring resource

Comment: That link only works for REST services? While mine is a SOAP service? And I tried all of that, I added the `@crossOrigin` annotation at my `@EndPoint` annotated class and it still gives me the same error.

Comment: I am sure that CORS setup for SOAP can be done in the same way as REST - WebMvcConfigurer corsConfigurer(). If that fails then https://docs.oracle.com/cd/E13222_01/wls/docs103/webserv_adv/handlers.html

Comment: Why do you call "origin of the webpage differs from the origin of the soap endpoint, which you are calling from js" an unsual scenario? Doesn't this happen often where your client is located elsewhere than your server?

Comment: Browser based SOAP clients are rare. Calls to SOAP services are invariably implemented in the back-end (ie server) and wrapped in REST/JSON - much more browser/js FE-developer friendly.